# How to use a framework just in a specific target in the iOS project by considering the need to import it in some classes?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, bridging-header

I have a project with multiple targets that one of them uses a special framework. The framework has been written with Objective-C and my project is written with Swift.

So I need to have a Bridging-header file where defines the framework. Now I use the communal  Bridging-header file but I don't want to use that framework on the other targets.

I tried to use the Bridging-header file separately for each target but I faced compile error which was couldn't find the framework in those of class files that import it!

[image: The red area is that the special framework]- **TL;DR**

**My question is: How can I add an Objective-C framework in the Swift project with multiple targets with considering that it should use in one target as well as the bridging-header file?**

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of days, I could manage to solve it.

1) Add a custom flag `(MY OPTIONS)` as well as `#ifdef` and `#endif` on the BridgingHeader.h file. like the following picture:

[image]

2) Select Target(specific) -> Build Settings -> Preprocessor Macros then add

> MY_OPTIONS=1

3) Select Target(specific) -> Build Settings -> Swift Compiler - Custom Flags -> Other Swift Flags then add

> -DMY_OPTIONS

4) On your class add this line to prevent get a compile error when compiling other targets

```
  #if MY_OPTIONS
      let specificVC = SpecificViewController()
      self.present(specificVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
  #endif
```